# how to connect sqlite to an android application?

Tags: android

I am trying to connect my android application to sqlite, i dont knw how to configure SD card in emulator to have a database... can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to configure an SD card in the emulator to create and use a sqlite database. You can create an SQLiteOpenHelper class that will do all the work of creating, opening, upgrading and other tasks on the database.

You can follow the tutorial on this link to understand the entire process. The blog has really explained the entire thing in a very simple manner and plus, also gives you the entire tutorial project as a download too.

[Android Sqlite Database tutorial](http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2010/08/04/android-database-tutorial/)